# Can anyone suggest a faster method to create this array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating this array to generate indices for my shader. This multiloop method is slow. Can anyone suggest any faster method to compute this array?

```
elems = []
ring_c = 24
slice_c = 235030
for si in range(slice_c - 1):
    elems += [si * ring_c, si * ring_c]
    for ri in range(ring_c + 1):
        ie = ri % ring_c
        elems += [ie + si * ring_c, ie + (si + 1) * ring_c]
elems = np.array(elems, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: You have to add description of what you are trying to do. Please edit your question and add details.

Comment: How do you know it's slow?  And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this some pre-calculation for some encryption algo? Then perhaps you can store the whole array once it's been generated and then just load it up from disk when needed?

Comment: @V.Sambor this code is taking approx. 2 sec to generate array. I want to use this array as an Indices list in OpenGL therefore on that aspect when screen has to be refreshed 15-20 times per second, it is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NumPy's vectorization and broadcasting abilities to speed up calculations. That'd be an approach from me, with some timings included (to be honest, code readability is quite reduced compared to the original loop approach, but if speed matters most...):

```py
import numpy as np
import time

ring_c = 24
slice_c = 235030

tic = time.perf_counter()

# Original solution
elems = []
for si in range(slice_c - 1):
    elems += [si * ring_c, si * ring_c]
    for ri in range(ring_c + 1):
        ie = ri % ring_c
        elems += [ie + si * ring_c, ie + (si + 1) * ring_c]

toc = time.perf_counter()

print('Time original solution [s]:', toc - tic)


tic = time.perf_counter()

# Vectorized approach
my_si = np.arange(slice_c - 1)
my_elems = np.repeat(ring_c * my_si, 2)
temp = np.empty(2 * my_si.size, my_si.dtype)
temp[0::2] = my_si
temp[1::2] = my_si + 1
my_ri = np.arange(ring_c + 1)
my_ie = np.expand_dims(my_ri % ring_c, axis=1)
my_si = temp * ring_c + my_ie
my_elems = np.vstack((my_elems, my_si))
N = my_elems.shape[1] // (slice_c - 1)
my_elems = list(my_elems.reshape((my_elems.shape[0], -1, N)).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape((np.prod(my_elems.shape), -1)).squeeze())

toc = time.perf_counter()

print('Time vectorized approach [s]: ', toc - tic)

print('Number of different elements: ', np.sum(np.abs(np.array(elems) - np.array(my_elems))))
```

Output:

```
Time original solution [s]: 4.765700837
Time vectorized approach [s]:  0.6265843100000001
Number of different elements:  0
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** For smaller arrays, the loop solution is faster than this vectorized approach!